# Estimation of creating index in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, index

We create new index on our production database, with a few fields, our database size is around 300GB and it works for one hour and do not finished yet.

- How can you estimate this operation?
- If we will stop index creation; How time it will make rollback by your approximate estimation?
- How can we check creation status in management studio?

Answer (score 2):

On SQL Server Std Ed, 2005-2014, there is no way to get est time remaining (and Sporri's answer on this thread is simply incorrect, sorry).

This thread has an actual answer to this question:
[SQL Server: How to track progress of CREATE INDEX command?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/139191/6229)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the estimated time remaining

```
select session_id
      ,command
      ,wait_time
      ,CAST((DATEDIFF(s,start_time,GetDate())%60) as varchar (10)) + ' sec' as running_time
      ,percent_complete
      ,CAST((estimated_completion_time %60000)/1000 as varchar (10)) + ' sec' as est_time_to_go
      ,dateadd(second,estimated_completion_time/1000, getdate()) as est_completion_time
 from sys.dm_exec_requests
```

The rollback time is highly dependent on how busy the server is but will take at least the same time as the elapsed time, safe bet is elapsed time x 1.5

Comment: On SQL Server 2014, the est completion time is basically 'now' and is not useful....